# android sdk error when import some projects

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I have SDK version 25, when i import a project in android studio this error occurs.

> "Install missing platform(s) and sync project".

If I click this link, I get another error, which says:

> "The following packages are not available: - Package id
>   platforms;android-23".

[sdk error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY1P2.png)

[my SDK version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e89N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the gradle version manually. For example if you are using `Android Studio` here is how:

1. Change the project view to **Android** if it's needed.
2. Go to the **app** folder.
3. Open the **build.gradle** (Module:app).
4. Change wherever you see the current SDK version (here, 23) to your desired version (here, 25).

   ### 5. Sync the project again.

And it's done.
**Note** that if you forgot anything needed the change, Android Studio will display a message and change it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your sdk platforms are missing. It must be from version 2.1 to 8.0. Try to reinstall your Studio and Sdk Manager.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This only works if you are getting sdk issue in a particular project and other project works fine**

One of the simplest fix I can suggest that worked for me

1. create a new android project and see if it works fine
2. If yes the Click File-->Export Settings(make sure to check all options) --->choose any location to save settings.
3. Go back to your project click File-->Import Settings from the saved location (make sure you select all options)
4. let the IDE Restart

   Hope this fixes the issue